# Load Multiple XML on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load points from two different XML files onto my Google Map. Points from both XML files load and show up, however when I click on the points loaded with the second xml file there is no balloon that pops up showing its html like the first xml files points do. If I remove the script that loads the first xml file, the balloons show up fine for the second xml file like so:

[image: What it should be doing]

I need to know how to map the points from both xml files and keep the balloons working, I can't figure it out.

Here is some of the code loading the xml files:

```
function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.214632, -97.799502),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var lastname = markers[i].getAttribute("lastname");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var fulladdress = markers[i].getAttribute("fulladdress");
          var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
          var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
          var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + " " + lastname +"</b> @ <b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + address + "</b> <br/>" + fulladdress;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('/kmz/<?php echo $name ?>.kmz');
          ctaLayer.setMap(map);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
      downloadUrl("/trucks/xmldata.php", function(data2) {
        var xml2 = data2.responseXML;
        var markers = xml2.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var unit = markers[i].getAttribute("unit");
          var lat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
          var lng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
          var last = markers[i].getAttribute("last");
          var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
          var speed = markers[i].getAttribute("speed");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var truck = markers[i].getAttribute("truck");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = truck + "<br>Speed: " + speed + "<br>State: " + state + "<br>Address: " + address + "<br>Last Updated: " + last;
          var icon = customIcons[unit] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
    }
    });
    }


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help. If you need more explanation, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I was making a simple mistake. I was not calling

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

after I called my second xml file. Adding this after the second downloadUrl() script fixed my issue.